# How to write paragraph only on left side using HTML

Tags: html

How to write a paragraph in HTML only on its left side? The desired output is similar to this:

[Left paragraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uroZO.png)

How to pull it off? Thanks!

Comment: And what do you have now? Left-alignment is, broadly speaking, the default text alignment in an HTML render. So if that's not what you're seeing, then you've done something to subvert it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo ...and it was cumbersome lol! I just sprinkled <br> anywhere to get the desired effect....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add on the < p > tag the `style="text-align: left"` CSS parameter, like this:

```
<p style="text-align: left"> Text here </p>
```

This goes for p, span, divs and etc. You can also make it by adding at CSS  or the style.css document the `p {text-align: left}`. If you want all of your page text to be align to the left, you can just add to text-align CSS to the body, like this:

```
<style>
body { text-align: left }
</style>
```

This is pretty basic CSS, you can check it more at the W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text_align.asp

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result, this is the HTML code...:-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Know Posporo</h1>

<p style="text-align:left;width: 50%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut itaque         porro aut aliquid voluptas est fugit consequatur. At dolores voluptas  ut reprehenderit nulla eum adipisci fuga ut similique assumenda cum ipsum enim. Eum enim assumenda non aspernatur numquam et voluptatem sunt sed dignissimos enim et cupiditate  perferendis. Cum rerum  assumenda ut maxime quos et distinctio quis et dolor suscipit.
<br>
<br>
Sed enim numquam aut voluptate tempore sed magnam nisi rem nulla incidunt non iste iste et consequatur  dignissimos? Rem placeat ratione aut rerum Quis quo velit laborum qui laudantium aliquid sed quas natus  At quia illum ea dolor adipisci. Qui voluptatem nostrum sit galisum enim in dicta rerum non debitis quos aut quisquam doloremque.
<br>
<br>
Aut laudantium asperiores est provident nulla eum porro consequatur id quos voluptatem sit beatae quidem  est eius distinctio. At voluptas quaerat aut inventore internos id quae quas eos praesentium veniam qui  omnis veniam et similique voluptatem qui molestiae autem. Qui voluptatem delectus sit nisi magnam qui quia soluta non dicta quis sed Quis iusto sit consequatur veritatis. Qui numquam atque qui fuga magni sit maxime necessitatibus id nostrum quia?</p>

</body>
</html>
```